# Converting int to double in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I can not get a simple conversion from `int` to `double` to work

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int i = 8;
  double d1 = i;
  double d2 = static_cast<double>(i);
  std::cout << "i = " << i << ", d1 = " << d1 << ", d2 = " << d2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`d1` and `d2` equals `8`, instead of `8.0`, not only in `stdout`, but also in the debugger of QtCreator.

AFAIK, `d1` and `d2` should be `8.0`, shouldn't then?

Can anyone, please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

I am setting g++ compiler, verion 7.4.0, conformance to C++11.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and `d1` and `d2` are 8.0. If a `double` value does not have a fractional part, the default formatting will not format a decimal point.

Comment: ***Can anyone, please, tell me what am I doing wrong?*** Formatting the output.

Comment: use `std::fixed` if you want to see the decimal

Comment: http://ideone.com/DnIp40

Comment: double d1 = i / 1.0 can convert your int to a double.  I don’t think you need to cast.

Comment: @ManLaw — you’re right that there is no need for a cast. There’s also no need for that division. Assigning an `int` value to a `double` works just fine, with an implicit conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker Forgot about the implicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I know that the output would need to be formated, but what I could no understand is why QtCreator debugger did not show any precision

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can not get a simple conversion from int to double to work

Actually, the conversion itself works just fine.

> d1 and d2 equals 8, instead of 8.0

8 and 8.0 are two ways of representing the same value as a string. There is no difference in the value.

> AFAIK, d1 and d2 should be 8.0, shouldn't then?

They are, because 8 and 8.0 are the same exact value.

> Can anyone, please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Your mistake is expecting the output to be 8.0. The correct output is 8, because of the default formatting settings of the output stream.

Another mistake is assuming that there is a problem with the conversion from int to double, when the problem is actually in the formatting of the textual output.

If your intention was to output 8.0, then your mistake was to not use the correct stream manipulators to achieve that format. In particular, you need to use the `std::fixed` manipulator to show fixed number of decimals, even when they are zero. You can use `std::setprecision` to set the number of decimals to show. Depending on how you want the output formatted in different cases, `std::showpoint` might also be an option.

Comment: I understand the need of formating for stdout output, but I could not understand why QtCreator debugger did not show any precision. Thansk!

Comment: @canellas what did the documentation of QtCreator debugger say  about the format it uses for floating point variables?

Comment: there is right clicking on a variable, a 'Change Value Display Format' menu shows. I tried a few options, but none worked. That is ok, I realize that is just a displaying issue, the value is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Make no mistake, `d1` and `d2` are `double`s. You need [`std::setprecision()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) (and apparently [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/)) too found in the header [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  int i = 8;
  double d1 = i;
  double d2 = static_cast<double>(i);
  std::cout << "i = " << i << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << ", d1 = " << d1 << ", d2 = " << d2 << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. std::setprecision() without a std::fixed() will not do after decimal points. This will just do up to 2 digits regardless where decimal is

Comment: Fixed (I think)

Comment: Or just [std::showpoint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint). You make the right point: the problem is in the display and not the conversion.

Comment: @Chipster, yes fixed +1.